# AngularJS : $watch not triggered on change ($scope issue with include page)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Html:**

```
Filter: 
<input type="radio" ng-model="Type" value="Rear"> Rear
<input type="radio" ng-model="Type" value="Front"> Front
<br>
Select:
<name-value-select entry="entry" field="axleType" options="filterTypes"></name-value-select>
```

**Directive:**

```
  .directive('nameValueSelect', function () {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        entry: "=",
        field: "@",
        options: "=",
        onInputChange: "&"
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {

        $scope.onChange = function () {
            console.log("selected changed");
            $scope.entry.type = $scope.option.value;
            $scope.onInputChange();
        };

        var getItemForValue = function (value) {
            var item = null;
            $scope.options.forEach(function (_option) {
                if (_option.value == value) {
                    item = _option;
                }
            });
            return item;
        };

        $scope.$watch("entry", function () {
            console.log("entry changed");
            $scope.option = getItemForValue($scope.entry[$scope.field]);
        }, true);

    },
    template: '<select ng-model="option" ng-options="o.Description for o in options" ng-change="onChange()"><option value="" selected="selected">Please Select </option></select>'

};  })
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.Description = '';
$scope.entry = {Description: ''};
$scope.Type = 'Front';
$scope.entry.type = '';


$scope.$watch('Type', function (Type) {
    $scope.filterTypes = [];
    $scope.axleTypes = new API.GetAxleTypes(function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.axleTypes, function(axleType) {
            if (axleType.Type == Type) {
                this.push(axleType);
            }
            // if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$digest(); // tried this, does not have any affect
    }, $scope.filterTypes); // '}, $scope.filterTypes, true)'--> did nothing for me here     
}); 
    $scope.filterTypes.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.Description.localeCompare(b.Description);
    });
}); // '}, true)' --> did nothing for me here
```

**Problem:**

The custom select control does initially populate with items of Type 'Front', and would also populate with 'Rear' if I made Rear the default.

**However, when toggling between radio buttons, the watch function is not called and the select does not populate with items meeting newly selected filter type.**

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**Narrowed Down the Problem:**
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

When moving this to a stand alone project, I discovered my code above works :-(

**Here is the original select NOT as a custom directive:**

```
    <select ng-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle" ng-options="axleType.Description for axleType in axleTypes | filterByType: 'Front' | orderBy:'Description'"  id="frontAxles" class="formRequire" required>            
        <option value="" selected>Select Axle Type ..</option>  
    </select>
```

**Here is the select control as a custom directive:**

```
  <name-value-select   entry="entry" field="axleType" options="filterTypes"></name-value-select>
```

Clearly this is the issue: **"ng-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle"**

If I take the directive "name-value-select" and move it to the parent page, in lieu of a include statement, it works.

But that is not what I want. So I need to leave it in the include page.

Yet, if I take the **ng-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle"** and add it to ANY element on the include page, nothing works.

Any with no **ng-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle"**, still nothing works.

I can see the issue is scope yet I do not see how to correct it.

Ughh!!! Still no solution.

//
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 **Mark Rajcok**
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

As always thanks for your help. Although, I do not think I made myself clear on point 2 when I said I had scenarios where I wanted the code to pre-filter and not the user. I figured it out though. So for anyone looking to abstract out controls via a directive, and, as in this case, where a filtering process is performed both by the user and in code, here is the plunker solution:

**http://plnkr.co/edit/tnXgPKADfr5Okvj8oV2S?p=preview**

Comment: its better if you set up plunker or fiddle demo for the problem

Comment: Mark see above comment addressed to you.

Comment: You don't want the same controller twice/nested.  Can you set up a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) (using ng-include)?  Or at least show where you are using ng-include?  It is not clear which HTML is being ng-included.  I also don't understand what `$scope.Type` and `$scope.entry.type` are for.  If your directive is supposed to be watching the radio buttons change, then the radio buttons need to use `entry.type`.  Also, `on-input-change` is not specified in your HTML, so your `&' binding won't work in the directive. (BTW, I did not get notified of your comment above... you need to use @Mark.)

Comment: @MarkRajcok, see comments above sNJ dude

Comment: @MarkRajcok you there?

Comment: Scott, I will try to get to this sometime today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q7NwuUDsFUXWcsv4NCaM?p=preview), I reworked the code to allow the user to select either "Rear" or "Front", and the select list will dynamically update.  The selected value is available as `$scope.selected.item` on the MainCtrl scope.  (There was a lot of unnecessary code in the directive that I removed.  onChange handlers aren't needed when ng-model is being used.)

```
<name-value-select selected-item="selected.item" options="filterTypes">
</name-value-select>

app.directive('nameValueSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            selectedItem: "=",
            options: '='
        },
        template: ...
```

Since ng-include creates a child scope, all primitive properties were converted to object properties, so that JavaScript prototypal inheritance will work as expected (i.e., when values are changed, $scope objects defined in the MainCtrl get changed rather than new primitive properties being created on local scopes).

I believe the plunker referenced above will satisfy your "point 1".

I will now look at creating a plunker for "point 2"... (I'll add a comment when I update this answer).

---

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V841HRwdiumD18gX7N0N?p=preview) filters the select list in the directive:

```
<name-value-select selected-item="selected.item" choice="choice.type"
 options="myTypes"></name-value-select>

app.directive('nameValueSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            selectedItem: "=",
            choice:  "=",
            options: "=",
        },
        controller: function($scope)  {
          $scope.$watch('choice', function (selectedType) {
            $scope.selectedItem = '';  // clear selection
            $scope.filterTypes = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.options, function (type) {
              if (type.Type === selectedType) {
                this.push(type);
               }
            }, $scope.filterTypes);
            $scope.filterTypes.sort(function (a, b) {
              return a.Description.localeCompare(b.Description);
            });
          });
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="selectedItem" ' +
         'ng-options="o.Description for o in filterTypes">' +
         '<option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>' +
         '</select>'
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not exactly understand your request, but I just assume that you want to dynamically change the content of a select according to the value a radio button group. The select is filtered and sorted and you may choose which field of the data to display.

You may have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLNWHvVDyyxqwQaENarO?p=preview) which contains a demo with few modifications.

**HTML**

```
Filter: 
<input type="radio" ng-model="filter.type" value="rear"> Rear
<input type="radio" ng-model="filter.type" value="front"> Front
<br />
Field:
<select ng-model="filter.field" ng-options="item for item in fields"></select>
<br />
Select:
<select ng-model="entry" ng-options="item[filter.field] for item in entries | filter:type=filter.type | orderBy:filter.field">
  <option value="">Default</option>
</select>
<br />
Selected: <span>{{entry}}</span>

<h2>Alternative</h2>
Filter: <span>{{filter}}</span>
<br />
<select ng-model="altentry" ng-options="item[filter.field] for item in altentries | orderBy:filter.field">
  <option value="">Default</option>
</select>
<br />
Selected: <span>{{altentry}}</span>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  /* Default filter values */
  $scope.filter = {
    type: 'rear',
    field: 'name'
  };

  /* List of fields */
  $scope.fields = [
    "id", "type", "name"
  ];

  /* Data coming from an API */
  $scope.entries = [
    {"id":1, "type":"rear", "name":"Rear Part 01"},
    {"id":2, "type":"rear", "name":"Rear Part 03"},
    {"id":3, "type":"rear", "name":"Rear Part 05"},
    {"id":4, "type":"rear", "name":"Rear Part 02"},
    {"id":5, "type":"rear", "name":"Rear Part 04"},
    {"id":6, "type":"front", "name":"Front Part 01"},
    {"id":7, "type":"front", "name":"Front Part 03"},
    {"id":8, "type":"front", "name":"Front Part 05"},
    {"id":9, "type":"front", "name":"Front Part 02"},
    {"id":10, "type":"front", "name":"Front Part 04"},
  ];

  /* Simulate different ajax return */
  $scope.$watch('filter.type', function(newval, oldval) {
    if (newval || newval !== oldval) {
      $scope.altentries = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.entries, function(v,k) {
        if (v.type === $scope.filter.type) {
          $scope.altentries.push(v);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  /* Monitoring any selected value */
  $scope.$watch('entry', function(newval, oldval) {
    console.log('entry:', oldval, newval);
  }, true);

  $scope.$watch('altentry', function(newval, oldval) {
    console.log('altentry:', oldval, newval);
  }, true);

});
```